# amp-carousel has a misplaced next and previous image arrows

Tags: html, css, templates, amp-html

i am using a template from [AMP Start](https://www.ampstart.com/components). 
i have used the amp-carousel.
the arrow images for next image and previous image buttons are on top of the screen and are not visible.
 how can i fix this? 
  [image one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VM5U.jpg)
  [image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBxqb.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do following things :

```
.amp-carousel-button .amp-carousel-button-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
.amp-carousel-button .amp-carousel-button-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
```

or else replace default indicators to custom indicators using following link : 
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-carousel/amp-carousel.md

Comment: thanks, this works but after sliding through a couple of images the arrows disappear. any clue as to how i can fix this?

Comment: I exactly don't  know but I think if you use 'z-index: 1' to both arrows then it will help.

Comment: we had disappearing arrow problem and switched to the SVG example from above. We also use: `fill='%23FFF' fill-rule='evenodd'`

Comment: where do you use these properties?

Answer (score -1):

To dont let hide arrows try to add type=slides in amp-carousel